# "stat -f" says "Type: fuseblk". It should be "Type: fuse"

Tags: linux, coreutils, fuse

If I run `stat -f .` on a `bindfs` or `sshfs` filesystem, it shows "Type: fuseblk".  This is not right.  Unlike `ntfs-3g`, these filesystems are not implemented using a block device.  If I run `findmnt`, it shows their type as just `fuse`.

Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this bug is too late to fix.  (I.e. it is effectively now also a feature :-).

Currently `S_MAGIC_FUSEBLK` is defined to represent what I think the kernel internally calls [FUSE_SUPER_MAGIC](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/fs/fuse/inode.c#L405).  (Google suggests it might be defined in "fs.h"?  But I can't find "fs.h" in [coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.30/src/stat.c#L343)).

`stat -f .` prints `S_MAGIC_FUSEBLK` as "Type: fuseblk", which sounds reasonable.  The problem is the exact same magic also returned for non-block FUSE filesystems.  This is in one of the fields returned by the Linux system call `statfs()`.  I suspect the original author only tested with block-based FUSE filesystems, like `ntfs-3g`.

I searched the web about this and only found a thread on the original patch.  Conveniently, the same thread explained backwards compatibility concerns, as a reason not to update the description of another filesystem type.  If this is valid, it sounds like both of the descriptions have now been in place too long, and changing them would be too risky.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-12/msg00229.html